# Automate sending individual E-mails and attachments to 100+ different recievers

Tags: email

I have an issue I want to solve, I need to send about 130 emails with different attachments to different receivers.

Optimally I want to create a standard(for the layout) PDF:s and have a table(in the PDF) which will vary depending on the receiver. I want to retreive the data(about 5 rows and 13 columns each), in a poor mans db(excel) or MySQL DB and retrieve the email adress of course. I then want the code to loop until all 130 e-mails are sent.

OS:Windows 7

One ugly alternative is to write a Powershell script to do this, with a .msg-file and manual created pdfs. But this wouldn't be scalable in the long term this is a code which needs to be active once a year, so I really need to figure this out.

I have only experiences in python and basic scripts, I don't even know where to start and what language to use.

Comment: Your approach "I need to send about 130 emails with different attachments to different receivers" looks like a spam

Comment: @dude Haha did not reflect on that att all, lol. No it's actually for a side project of mine.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Welcome to superuser. Please have a look on our [help center](http://superuser.com/help) to learn what type off questions you may ask here. Your current question is off-topic for several reasons.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing some very weird version of a mail merge.